# Voting Behaviour and Random Samples in Excel

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, voting-theory

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to detect suspicious voting behavior in my country in South America. The way elections work is that each region has a several election centers with voting tables, with an average of 229 voters each (+/- 50).

One candidate got 0 votes in 18 voting tables, which I think is highly unlikely, despite the fact she only had 10.7% of the vote in that region overall. So, here are the facts:

Total Region Votes: 722,793

Candidate A: 645,152 ( 89.258%)

Candidate B: 77,641 (10.742%)

Voting Tables: 3159

Votes per table (total votes/voting tables): 229 (+/- 50)

Question, what is the probability that Candidate B got 0 votes in 1, 5, 10 and 18 voting tables?

Put another way, if we were to take 3159 random samples of 229 votes each (+/-50) from all the votes (722,793) what is the probability of pulling out "0" votes on a sample for Candidate B once, 5, 10 and 18 times? I assume the probability would fall exponentially.

If there is a way to simulate this in Excel, any detail would be much appreciated.

p.s. This assumes that the votes per table are normally distributed, which I do not know for a fact, but given the very large sample size and similarities in voter preference composition for that region I suspect would be the case.

Comment: If everything were perfectly random (highly unlikely in reality) a candidate getting no votes in a station has a probability of $(1-p)^n$ where $p$ is the probability of a vote for the candidate and $n$ is the number of votes in the station.

Comment: Specifically, if B has proportion $p =0.107$ of the vote the probability of no votes in $n = 229$ is given by R code `dbinom(0, 229, .107)`, which returns $ 5.558839e-12,$ where `e-12` means to move the decimal point 12 places to the left. // However, it is possible that there are 'tables' where local voters behave contrary to the overall proportions. (Perhaps B gave a speech in that area that was not well received.) // Best for all candidates to have representatives watching at all tables to ensure voting rules are followed.